# What To Do After Creating Bootable USB

Tags: system-installation

For the first time i have installed Ubuntu on my laptop but when i booted my laptop it was not showing options to select between the two OS i.e i have installed Windows8 on laptop and created bootable USB stick for Ubuntu and then restarted my computer and changed boot device to USB and selected to use first device (HDD) for getting it started (linux) then i connected to internet,would it automatically upload any of my document from HDD ?????

how to install various software(application) to Ubuntu like vlc, etc.

Comment: first, did you install Ubuntu? can you follow [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/152902/10698) and tell me where you are?.

Comment: @Alvar the OP has installed Windows 8. [Installing Ubuntu on a pre-installed Windows 8 64 bit system (uefi supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) may also be useful.

Comment: that's true, but it wasn't for sure that Ubuntu got installed so I want him/her to tell us what he/she has done so far. So we know what help to give. @AvinashRaj doesn't answer the questions since we don't know what the question is....

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Thank you for your post, however, we are having a bit difficulties in understanding what actually is the question, what you did and where you are.

Answer (score 1):

> I have installed Ubuntu on my laptop but when i booted my laptop it was not showing options to select between the two OS.

- Boot into Ubuntu and then run `sudo update-grub` command on the terminal(ctrl+alt+t).

> how to install various software(application) to Ubuntu like vlc, etc

- [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

> would it automatically upload any of my document from HDD ?

- No, Unless you enabled online storage services.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shound part your DD using gparted after creating your bootabel usb stick, but before you need to save all your important infos somewhere else because there's a big chance you lose everything in the process of parting your DD, (disque dure in french I don't know what it is in English), when parting you'll need 3 sections : linux, Windows and système d'exploitation DATA.
you'll also need the command chkdsk.
I suggest you to take this infos and Google them and check tutorials till you understand what you'll need to do and why.
good luck.
if you've already sorted this problem out feel free to share your version of the story may help other people.

Comment: In English it's HDD (hard disk drive).